# Why this code doesn't print a circle in python using turtle library?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have recently started using the `turtle` library but I don't understand why it doesn't print circles when I execute the following code:

```py
from turtle import *

color('green')
speed(11)

for i in range(60):
    circle(i * 1.5)
    right(4)

    hideturtle()
    done()
```

Comment: Did you mean to leave `done()` inside the loop?

Comment: @quamrana omg you're right thank you so much! 

Answer (score 0):

If we treat this as simply an indentation problem, then the following whitespace cleanup:

```
from turtle import *

color('green')
speed('fastest')

for i in range(60):
    circle(i * 1.5)
    right(4)

hideturtle()
done()
```

runs fine and prints circles:

[image]

If you were expecting something else to be printed, please describe your desired output.